# Why are there so few posts with zero comments?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

While researching my theory that [showing comments costs votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210266/1438), I noticed that there are surprisingly few posts with zero comments.  Here's what the [distribution](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/152276/comment-count-distribution-flawed#graph) looks like:

[image: Count vs. number of comments]

That graph was generated using the following SQL:

```sql
select CommentCount, count(*) 
from Posts 
where CommentCount < 30
group by CommentCount
order by CommentCount
```

The huge distribution disconnect makes me think comments are not being counted correctly.

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic on Meta Stack Overflow... ah, whatever.

Answer (score 20):

### Most posts have `NULL` in the `CommentCount` field

The `CommentCount < 30` clause explicitly filters out rows where `CommentCount is NULL`.  (This is because `NULL` represents the absence of data so logical operators involving `NULL` always return false.)  Thankfully, SQL flavors offer ways to treat `NULL` as something else (usually zero):

```sql
select isnull(CommentCount, 0), count(*) 
from Posts 
group by isnull(CommentCount, 0)
order by isnull(CommentCount, 0)
```

This results in a more likely looking [distribution](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/152159/comment-count-distribution#graph):

[image: Count vs. number of comments (corrected)]

### What does `NULL` mean in `CommentCount`?

By comparing the posts with `0` comments to those with `NULL`, it seems that the row is created with a null `CommentCount` field.  As comments are added, the field is updated to reflect the number of comments on the post.  When comments are removed, the field is decremented.  When *all* comments are removed the field becomes `0`.  So:

- `NULL`—No comments have ever been added to the post.
- `0`—Comments have been added to the post, but they've all been removed.

Comment: FWIW: you'll run into the same thing with AnswerCount. One of those little pitfalls that can send you waaay too far down a wrong path unless you regularly sanity-check your results by running queries that rely on normalized data.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps we should annotate the type in the schema for nullable columns...

Comment: It's a "count" field @Tim. It would make more sense if it were defaulted to 0 by SE; though maybe the nuance's that Jon is describing are used for some purpose...

Comment: Shouldn't that be made a `NOT NULL` field (possible along with `DEFAULT 0`)?

Comment: See also: [What is the purpose of SET NULL in Delete/Update Foreign Keys constraints?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5182/170252), [Why shouldn't we allow NULLs?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5227/170252), or [NULL or NOT NULL by default?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/63/170252) from our DBA.SE site. That's how it was designed, with both NULL and 0.