# Why do some comments on Russian-language sites have negative scores?

Tags: bug, comments, data-explorer

At least on two sites: [SO on Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) and [Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) SE Data Explorer [returns](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/934139/comment-with-negative-score) a lot of comments with negative score [-6...-1]:

> [image: negative]

Actual comments look like normal comment without upvotes.

What is this? An echo of migration from [hashcode.ru](http://hashcode.ru)?

Comment: What happens if you upvote one of those comments?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog nothing special, it gots upvote. But due to the delay of SEDE data update you won't know right now.

Comment: A score of 1 you mean?

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog for all other comments N score mean N upvotes.

Comment: maybe they were answers and a mod pressed the magic 'convert to comment' button?

Comment: @AakashM, yep, seems so, for example for this [comment](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/22076/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-linux-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-windows#comment22107_22076). It was answer with -10 before

Comment: @AakashM not sure, cause big SO doesn't have any one. Do you believe that 'convert to comment' was never pressed on SO? Even more in such case there were deleted answers on questions, but they don't exists.

Comment: Migration from the original site appears to make more sense: they copied the score to database as-is, and they do have sanity check when displaying preventing negative score from being displayed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard [comments v 2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igO38.png).

Comment: @älёxölüt why can't I downvote your comment? Do I need more rep for this?

Answer (score 9):

Upon investigating this issue further it does seem that these are leftovers from the migration.

The most recent voting history we have in our databases (that I could find) is for April 2015 (Technically, March 31st, but oh well). This means that we do not have the actual votes for these comments and thus I can't say where they came from with certainty.

The migration theory is supported by the fact that the most recent comment with a negative score is from March 12th 2015, if it was from answers being turned into comments there would be more recent ones.