# VoteTypeIds in the context of Comments for StackOverflow Posts

Tags: support, comments, voting, down-votes, data-explorer

Known information:

1. As per [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253182/4315883) comments can't be downvoted.
2. VoteTypeId 3 means downvote on a given post. [referred answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157536/500591)

My Assumption: Comments should not be downvoted and therefore **Votes** table on SEDE StackoverFlow (StackExchange Data Explorer) **should not have entries** with **VoteTypeId = 3** for any comment as a *PostId*.

Result:

I ran the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1029032/bugged) on SEDE StackOverflow to test my assumption. Following query extracts all the comments of answers of a given QuestionId and finds their entries in *Votes* table.

```
select * from votes where postid in
(select id from comments where postid in 
(select id from posts where parentid = 7172459))
```

I found that there are several entries for some comments with *VoteTypeId = 3*.

Can anyone please explain if the **VoteTypeIds** have different notion when considered them in the context of a **Comment**?

Comment: If you're seeing this on Russian-language sites, it could be a bug with the migration from hashcode.ru, see [Why do some comments on Russian-language sites have negative scores?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318724/why-do-some-comments-on-russian-language-sites-have-negative-scores). If not, please edit and comment.

Comment: I am seeing this on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. Where can I get Votes information for Comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PostId in the votes table is a foreignkey to the Post table and the Posts table only. The id's found there don't relate in anyway to the comments table. Joining them makes no sense from an information point of view.

```
    +------+
    |      |1
    |   +----------------+              +------------------+
    |   |                |              |                  |
    |   |                |              |    Votes         |
    |   |   Posts        |1            *|    -VoteTypeId   |
    |   |    -Id         +--------------+    -PostId       |
    +---|    -ParentId   |              |                  |
       *|                |              |                  |
        +----------------+              +------------------+
                | 1
                |
                |
                |
                |                       +----------------+
                |                       |                |
                |                       |   Comments     |
                |                      *|   -Id          |
                +-----------------------|   -PostId      |
                                        |   -Score       |
                                        |                |
                                        +----------------+
```

Use the score attribute in the comments table to find how many times the comment was upvoted. You can't get any extra meta-data about that score, like creationdate of the vote.

See [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) for the full schema and also scroll down to the ERD in the second answer.

Comment: Is there a way to get last upvote date for a comment?

Comment: @AdityaNarkar no, you can't get that info. It is not in the public SEDE and I'm not even sure if it is internally tracked.

Comment: Definitely agree of it not being in public SEDE, however I think it's definitely being tracked internally. For example, one of the features in SO is not being able to upvote a comment again after you upvoted and undo.

You can try this by upvoting a comment, then cancel the upvote and tried upvoting again. You will get a prompt saying that you cannot do this. This means that they must be tracking userId which has previously upvoted a comment.

Comment: @velociraptor11 That is true, I was making an educated guess about the upvote *date*.