# Should I delete comments on deleted answers?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, deleted-answers

When I provide an answer on Stack Overflow, it might be incorrect, or OP has further requests, so it could be end up with lots of comments below it. And eventually I deleted the answer for many reasons.

Is it a good practice to delete all my comments? I also tired a couple of times to flag other comments, but they always get "declined" in the flag history. Is it normal?

I understand 10k users can view deleted answers, so I often replace the content of my deleted answer with a placehoder text like "---deleted---" etc. Just to avoid people to see the incorrect content. Is that a good thing to do? Because I often see many deleted answers on a page, and they could take a large space of the page, makes it harder to find the real useful information.

Comment: Tangentially related: [Always collapse comments on deleted answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269012/213963)