# Comment hierarchy on SE

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

**Introduction**

There are many questions on SE with the long and fruitful discussions in comments. Such discussions often involve replying to other commenters using `@username` approach

**Problem**

Possibly, this is my subjective experience, but sometimes it is hard to follow which comment replies to which. Vice versa, it is sometimes hard to find the reply to the comment among a pile of others. For instance, the comments by Peter reply to the fist two commenters, but it takes some mental effort to understand this. To get clearer understanding of the discussion, reader needs to parse through the comments above and to restore the links.

[image]

**Proposed solution - comment hierarchy**

There is nothing innovative in this feature request, some popular websites use this technique (e.g. Quora, Reddit, ). The example from Reddit is shown on the screenshot below:

[image]

As we can see, this solution provides several advantages for users compared to the existing structure:

- Indentation provides additional clarity for the reader
- Eliminate the misspelling of `@username` and, thus, making sure that the right person is notified when gets a reply
- Similarly, if the commenter forgets to add `@` the right person would still be notified
- No need to see whether the question in comments received a reply or not
- Parent and children comments are close to each other - so it is very easy to focus only on one aspect of discussion
- If the comment receives more that one reply, it is much easier to track all replies
- Ability to minimize the comment branches allow to focus on the single one, or just to save space on the page

**Shortcomings**

Certainly, there are possible drawbacks of the solutions:

- User cannot answer to several people. AFAIK  with the current system we can't either (notification is sent only to one)
- Chronicity is partially lost, since it is not obvious when the comment was added. Can be mitigated by adding sorting options
- The text shrinks as the replies go deeper, due to indent.
- Lack of space for realization of modification

I think the proposed modification would improve the user experience primarily because it would bring more structure to the discussions in comments. However, due to the possible opposition of experienced users, this feature may be added as option.

Comment: related: [Help us figure out a way to handle the explosion of comments on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180325/165773) and [How can we measure the cost of displaying comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210265/165773)

Comment: Related design from site creator: [Discussions: Flat or Threaded?](http://blog.codinghorror.com/discussions-flat-or-threaded/) and [Web Discussions: Flat by Design](http://blog.codinghorror.com/web-discussions-flat-by-design/).  I would also encourage following that first link to Jeff's commentary on [A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-group-is-its-own-worst-enemy/) and note that the current comment design is an attempt to prevent the problems of comments not scaling well.

Answer (score 6):

There's not supposed to *be* long, threaded conversations in the comments. Comments are supposed to be temporary and to prompt the author for clarifications or to note issues with the post.

From the Help Center:

> **What are comments?**
>   Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. ...
>
> **When should I comment?**
>   You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).
>
> **When shouldn't I comment?**
>       ...
>
> - **Answering a question** or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);
>     ...
> - **Secondary discussion** or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;

If there need to be long conversations attached to a post, there's something wrong.

We need better comment moderation (getting rid of outdated comments) rather than more robust comments.

Answer (score 2):

There's <strike>an app</strike> a script for that on Stack Apps: [Threaded comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2050/threaded-comments). It does more or less what you want without any major damage to the environment.