# What algorithm is used to pick which comments are shown and which are hidden?

Tags: discussion, comments, sorting

What algorithm or parameters decides, in questions or answers with a large number of comments, which comments are immediately visible (right below main text) and which are hidden under `add / show X more comments` link?

I assumed, that all comments are ordered by the date, they were made and the most recent one are visible at once, while the oldest one are hidden under above mentioned links. Turns out, I'm wrong.

In comments-queues, that look more like chat or question-answer stream (against SE rules, but even though existing) it is often, that parts of such stream are hidden and parts are show. Which makes such "chat" sometimes unreadable or even without any sense. When `add / show X more comments` link is clicked, you can clearly see (in this chat-like situations), that some comments are added in between others and only then, all of them together, formulate a readable "discussion".

For (too) many times I've run into situation, that upon displaying a page and looking at comments seen directly I got the feeling like "*what are those guys talking about*". And only after revealing all comments, this chat-like discussion was readable. Before that, it often happened that only a serie of comments-questions were displayed, while all or most of comments-answers were hidden, making a total mess.

This really intrigues me, so I would like to now:

1. Why such behavior is introduced? What is the reason or purpose for starting with "mess"?
2. What is the algorithm for picking which comments are shown and which are hidden?
3. Why comments are not ordered by date with newest shown and oldest hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to address your 3 related questions backwards as that order seemed to make the most sense....

> Why comments are not ordered by date with newest shown and oldest hidden?

Comments are not supposed to be chronological everlasting conversations, they are designed to be used for clarifying posts, but can also be used for suggestions and non-answer hints.

Yes, people do get into conversations there, but that is not their purpose.  the reason they are ordered such that they are when filtered is so the "best" comments, judged by the number of helpful votes rise to the top.  The idea is that the highest voted comments are the most helpful to someone looking at the post and should be highlighted.

It is also not uncommon for comments to get deleted, which could result in break in the conversation so it would no longer make sense, so any chronological ordering would be destroyed at that point in time.

> What is the algorithm for picking which comments are shown and which are hidden?

As I sort of mentioned above, they are roughly ordered by vote with the highest votes rising to the top.  It does not specifically sort by vote count though as there is some chronological aspect to it, as seen in our of the more famous (or infamous) [answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/250725).  Here you can see that all of the shown comments are heavily upvoted, but the visible comments are still shown in chronological order.

> Why such behavior is introduced? What is the reason or purpose for starting with "mess"?

I covered this above again, but it is design to make the most "helpful" comments rise to the top, and keep long comment chains hidden unless someone wants to see what the discussion was about.

---

As a side note, if you see a post with a long comment chain that is really just a "chatty" conversation, feel free to flag the off-topic comments, or flag the entire post, and ask a moderator to clean up the comments.

Answer (score 2):

[The top 5 comments are shown, in chronological order](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/comments-top-n-shown/) when there are more than `n` comments. I can't find what `n` is. A change to the algorithm was [recently proposed but ultimately rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204402/hide-trivial-comments).

Comment: I loved the "We didn’t get to the user preference yet, but it’s coming". So typical.