# Best practices and advice how to shorten links to comments when including them in other comments? Can I safely drop the noredirect=1?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

When adding links to comments within other comments I often want to shorten them so that I can add fit more plain text within the character limit.

I usually start by removing the words of the title and one forward slash, and sometimes remove the `noredirect` bit, but I recognize that I don't really know what I'm doing.

Is it possible to state best practices and offer some advice on how to best shorten links to comments when including them in other comments? What does `noredirect=1` do for example, and what are the consequences of removing it?

Working examples that *appear to me* to be ripe for shortening:

- `https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/54293/is-there-any-demonstrated-or-even-proposed-technology-that-can-sterilize-a-space?noredirect=1#comment177960_54293`
- `https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41023/why-cant-we-build-a-huge-stationary-optical-telescope-inside-a-depression-simil/41027?noredirect=1#comment83925_41027`

Comment: You can always remove `https:`.

Comment: A while ago, I wrote an answer to [Documentation for Stack Exchange engine URLs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332237/295232) which contains (most of) the information you're looking for (but it's buried deep) - it does not mention the possibility of relative URLs though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an even shorter undocumented scheme for shortening comment URLs, that makes for links even shorter than Cave Johnson's answer: just take the comment ID, i.e. the first number in the `#comment[x]_[y]` fragment, and put it into `/posts/comments/[x]`.

Examples:

- `https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/54293/is-there-any-demonstrated-or-even-proposed-technology-that-can-sterilize-a-space?noredirect=1#comment177960_54293`
- `https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41023/why-cant-we-build-a-huge-stationary-optical-telescope-inside-a-depression-simil/41027?noredirect=1#comment83925_41027`

become:

- `https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/177960`
- `https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/83925`

respectively.

If the comment you're linking to is on the same site, you can drop the full URL portion and link to it as a relative URL, so these URLs would then become the following:

- `/posts/comments/177960`
- `/posts/comments/83925`

These only work if the linked comment is on the *same* site as the comment you're posting, as they omit the site part of the URL. Do note that such relative links will [break if the question is subsequently migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333880/377214), so only use them if the question is older than 60 days or you're *sure* it won't be migrated.

Comment: It’s not quite undocumented. This is how comments are linked in the timeline.

Comment: Nice, would be cool if there was a way to get this link from the ui.

Comment: @CaveJohnson As Sebastian Simon commented, such links are given in the timeline.

Comment: This is working nicely, thanks! Does it make sense here to add a `/usernumber` to the end to "get credit" for folks following the link the same way that links to posts do when clicking "Share"?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like I was able to get the comment link to work even when I removed the title segment from the urls. So I changed

- `https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/54293/is-there-any-demonstrated-or-even-proposed-technology-that-can-sterilize-a-space?noredirect=1#comment177960_54293`
- `https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41023/why-cant-we-build-a-huge-stationary-optical-telescope-inside-a-depression-simil/41027?noredirect=1#comment83925_41027`

to:

- `https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54293?noredirect=1#comment177960_54293`
- `https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/41023?noredirect=1#comment83925_41027`

Also note I changed `/questions/` to `/q/` to shorten the urls further.

I guess that removing the noredirect=1 part will cause the url to redirect to a duplicate post if the question has been closed as a duplicate and the the user is not logged in/anonymous (or possibly below a certain reputation?), which could result in an undesired effect.

Comment: The redirection is specifically for anonymous users who visit an unanswered duplicate ([reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125807/)). So if the question isn't close as a dupe, or has an answer, that bit could be removed as well